# Trouble with map()

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the values of a list using the `map` function but i am getting a strange result.

```
s = input("input some numbers: ")
i = map(int, s.split())
print(i)
```

gives:

```
input some numbers: 4 58 6
<map object at 0x00000000031AE7B8>
```

why does it not return ['4','58','6']?

Comment: Have you tried with print(str(i)) ?

Comment: Works for me as expected, can you give us some context? Python version? Are you using 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: i'm using python 3.2.2, there is no context at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using python 3 which returns generators instead of lists.

Call `list(x)` on the variable after you assign it the map generator.

Comment: It's worth noting you could also use a list comprehension as an alternative - ``[int(x) for x in s.split()]``. This is nice and readable, although in this (simple) case, I wouldn't say map is that unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `list(i)` to get `['4','58','6']` as `map` in python 3 returns a generator instead of a list.
Also, as Lattyware pointed in the comment of the first answer you better do this:

```
i = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

Comment: Why? [jamylak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10106900/722121) explains better.

Comment: He posted before me and explained it. So I did not :p